# Replacing background image onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background-image

I am replacing a background image on click but it is not working. Here is my html:

```
 <img id ='pet' src= 'http://ianon.info/pet_support/pic.png' height='200' width='200' style='border: 1px solid black'>;
```

Here is my JS+CSS:

```
 <input type="radio" name="field" value="4" onclick="document.getElementById('pet').style.border='30px solid transparent';document.getElementById('pet').style.border-image='url(http://ianon.info/pet_support/borders/pawprint.png) 120 round'"/> Paw Print Frame &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
```

I think it my be an issue my syntax following "onclick". Any pointers will be appreciated!

Comment: try extracting your onclick into a function, then wrap the background image url in quotes.

Comment: You should start by changing the img src attribute, instead of changing the background image.

Comment: @semperfids Yes, might be inefficient though, it will not always load the image from cache. Better to load both images once and use classes maybe?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have got to remove the code on your onClick. Replace it with a function, it's way more cleaner and less bug-prone.

```
<input type="radio" name="field" value="4" onclick="doSomething()"/> Paw Print Frame &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
```

then you'll have your script, it could be an external javascript file that you add at the end of your HTML, or you could also use the `<script></script>` tags to write JS between those.

```
<script>
function doSomething(){
    var petIMG = document.getElementById('pet');
    petIMG.style.border='30px solid transparent';
    petIMG.src='url(http://ianon.info/pet_support/borders/pawprint.png) 120 round'
}
</script>
```

This way it should work

Comment: Why use getElementById when you have jquery??

Comment: @PaulG Why use JQuery when you have getElementById ?? Why not also using AngularJS + ReactJS for his HTML ??
Jquery, for this small and short example, is absolutely not necessary. I believe OP is learning JS, i think it's better to not complicate the code by adding unnecessary frameworks to his project.

Comment: What if I am trying to manipulate the border-image attribute?

Comment: OP is using jquery, as his 'jquery' tag would suggest. if not? Then why put the tag in??

Comment: @PaulG, jQuery is not necessary to resolve the OP's problem. The img element is already assigned an id, and `getElementById` is [supported everywhere](http://caniuse.com/#search=getElementById).

Comment: @user1011332 `petIMG.style.border="the values you want"; `

Comment: @JorelLokiAmthor Also, jquery is not a framework, but is a javascript library, just figured I'd let you know.

Comment: @PaulG i'm sorry you feel like im at your throat cause i'm really not. You were adressing me a question and i simply answered it.

Comment: @JorelLokiAmthor No worries, I just figured that if you're gonna use jquery in your project (as the user seems to be based on his inclusion of the jquery tag in his question), then why not use its simple syntax as that's what it's for. BTW, greetings from Montreal!

Answer (score 2):

JQuery is very simple and short. To replace the background image when the radio button is clicked.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("[name=field:radio]").click(function(){
            $("[id=pet]").css("border", "30px solid transparent").css("background-image", "url(http://ianon.info/pet_support/borders/pawprint.png) 120 round");
        });
    });
</script>

<img id='pet' src='http://ianon.info/pet_support/pic.png' height='200' width='200' style='border: 1px solid black'>

<input type="radio" name="field" value="4"/> Paw Print Frame &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
```

Comment: What if there are multiple radio buttons and each one will result in a different border style?

Comment: then you have to write a jQuery click function event for each of them, specifying within the function the border style you want. Also remember to differentiate the multiple radio buttons by giving them a unique ID. instead of using $(["name=field:radio"), you use $("[id=uniqueid]") for each

Comment: if you like to learn more jquery very quickly check http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

You're rendering your image as an [HTML `<img>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img), but you're trying to change it as if it were set as a [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) in CSS. To render a different image, change your `img`'s 'src' attribute.

I.e. change:

```
document.getElementById('pet').style.backgroundImage='url(http://ianon.info/pet_su pport/borders/pawprint.png) 120 round';
```

to:

```
document.getElementById('pet').src = 'http://ianon.info/pet_support/borders/pawprint.png';
```